# Details about Github repository spring-project/spring-framework

Tags: spring, eclipse, github

What's the purpose of [spring-project/spring-framework](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework) repository in GitHub?

How to run this applications using eclipse?

Comment: It's not an application. It's the spring framework, as clearly indicated in the repo name, description, and README.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where Spring Framework source code is hosted.

If you want to start using Spring, you don't need their Github repository, I'd recommend starting at their official site: https://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/ There you can find the documentation, description of the subprojects that comprise Spring Framework, as well as instructions of how to use it. There is an example on their main page.

If you want to build an application, you could take a look at Spring Boot: https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/ The site, again, contains documentation, guides, examples and so on.

Here you can find information on how to run your Spring Boot application in Eclipse: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-running-your-application.html

They have their own IDE based on Eclipse: https://spring.io/tools/sts

And if you want to rebuild Spring from source or (more likely) learn how it works, then its Github repo will be useful for you.